# Java. Log4j. openjdk-7. Issue looks like infinite loop

Tags: linux, java, log4j2

Execution flow runs into something looking like infinite loop when it tryes to execute line

```
this.logger = LogManager.getLogger(SharedStorage.class.getName());
```

It is the first place in my program where Log4j 2 methods has been called. Furthermore such line has been placed at the very beginnig of my program.

The issue happens **only** at digitalocean.com and **only** if my app runs without jdb.
So when i run it on my developer mechine(Win 7 x64) or on my previous VPS(Ubuntu 12.10 x64) or on digitalocean.com(Ubuntu 12.04 x32) but with jdb everything works pretty well.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what causes the bug. But after i'd updated the log4j2 library from beta 4 to beta 9 code starts to work as it should.

Comment: Consider just deleting your question then, instead of giving yourself an answer totally useless for future visitors.